# Take value from JComboBox and convert it to int

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm completing a project in a Java and I'm working in Netbeans. So i have a comboBox (I'm using Swing) which includes pairs like (0,5) and I'm trying to decompose it and take the values of it(0 and 5) but i cant. I used getSelectedItem but it returns an object. I simply want the integer values. How can I get them from the combobox?

Comment: The crucial question is: What **type** are the elements in the combo box? Is this a `String`, like `"(0,5)"`, or is this an instance of a (own) class, like `PairOfIntegers`? The `getSelectedItem` method returns `Object`, but you can simply cast this object to the type that it actually has. (If you're not sure, just do a `System.out.println(cb.getSelectedItem().getClass());` and see what it says...)

Comment: let me know if I've helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

use  `getSelectedIndex();`  for JComboBox

return an integer specifying the currently selected list item, where 0 specifies the first item in the list; or -1 if no item is selected or if the currently selected item is not in the list

for info: [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedIndex())

then use a switch to take the fields selected.